# css - using grid-auto-column to create dynamic widths

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to get my css grid to either be 2 blocks per row (if there are enough items) or a single block that spans the entire width. However, I can't seem to get it to work using grid-auto-column.

The top block is what I want it to look like, and the bottom block is what my current css is creating.

```css
.flex1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
}

.grid1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: minmax(50%, 100%);
}

div.height {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex1">
  <div class="red height">
  </div>
  <div class="blue height">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="green height">
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="red height">
  </div>
  <div class="blue height">
  </div>
  <div class="green height">
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: in css you use `.grid1` and in html `class="grid"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, this isn't possible with *the Grid*, but it's a perfect and easy job for *Flexbox*, since you only need to handle *one* or *single dimensional layout*, in your case *rows*.

Below I'm giving you the shorter version of the desired result / behavior of *flex-items*, with less markup and styling:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* enables wrapping of flex-items */
}

.flex > div {
  flex: 1 0 50%; /* grows full width if alone in a row / doesn't shrink / initial width set to 50%, i.e. can't be less than 50% of the parent's width */
  height: 50px;
}

.red {background: red}
.blue {background: blue}
.green {background: green}
.yellow {background: yellow}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: okay, this was a good answer, no need for grid specifically then.

Comment: Ty, exactly, no need for grid in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Use     [`grid-template-areas: "a b" "c c";`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas)(change `.grid1` to `.grid` as in html)

Also set   `grid-area:;` to each div inside `.grid`

```css
.flex1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: minmax(50%, 100%);
  grid-template-areas: "a b" "c c";
}

div.height {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex1">
  <div class="red height">
  </div>
  <div class="blue height">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="green height">
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="red height" style="grid-area: a;">
  </div>
  <div class="blue height" style="grid-area: b;">
  </div>
  <div class="green height" style="grid-area: c;">
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: I need the green block to be stretched to 100%, since it's the sole block of that row

Comment: I guess that's currently a work around that's usable. But I was wondering more specifically with auto-columns because if I have a variable number of items, say it could be from 3 - 10 items, then how would I do it so it automatically generates it like that?

Comment: that one of the reason I would recommand you to use `flex` instead `grid`